# Font showing properly on some parts of page but not others

Tags: fonts, safari, mobile-safari

Not sure if anyone else has experienced problems with the Gotham font. I am using this font via the @font-face method, it is hosted on our server and is in woff and woff2 formats as below:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamLight';
    src: url('fonts/GothamLight/GothamLight.woff2?$staticlink$') format('woff2'), url('fonts/GothamLight/GothamLight.woff?$staticlink$') format('woff');
}
```

This format does not give me any trouble with other fonts.

The issue I'm having is inconsistency, the font renders in some places but not others, there is a fallback font but the div where the text should be is just empty white space. Then the next text div on the page will display the Gotham font fine. I don't think it is a code issue with any particular div on the page because as soon as I set another font everything is fine.

The main issues appear to be safari in general and particularly iPhone.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you set up a small demo so we can check it out? E.g. on Codepen.io

Comment: Not done this before so not too sure if it is of any use. Also the path to the font and images in my code is obviously referencing our server so is generating a 404 in this example, however what I am experiencing on mobile is that the top block of text, 'receive free samples...' is not rendered at all, however the rest of the text is fine, the 'summer skin..' onwards. They are both set to Gotham with Helvetica as a fallback.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tfox74qc/2/